# Xcode 7.0 Beta :- ibtool failed with exit code 255

Tags: ios, xcode

All, 
Trying to run an existing project as free prvivisining on xcode 7.0 Beta. I get below error, Any ideas how can i get rid of this. 
Error Stack

```
2015-06-26 14:16:16.042 ibtoold[16859:662960] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-8121.17/InterfaceBuilderKit/Document/Platform/IBIdiom.m:105
Details:  Assertion failed: !
Object:   <IBIPadIdiom: 0x7f8f53e1cb50>
Method:   -filePathWithTargetDeviceSuffixForBaseFilePath:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f8f53c09d80>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000104ba2ff9 -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x0000000104ba2b2d _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000104ba2d44 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x0000000104ba2ca6 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x0000000105c972b5 -[IBIdiom filePathWithTargetDeviceSuffixForBaseFilePath:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  5  0x000000010f8e6904 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  6  0x0000000105b66866 -[IBDocument finishCompilingWithOutputPath:options:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  7  0x0000000104961ff6 (in ibtoold)
  8  0x00000001049644dc (in ibtoold)
  9  0x0000000104967f15 (in ibtoold)
 10  0x00000001049685c9 (in ibtoold)
 11  0x00000001049684a0 (in ibtoold)
 12  0x0000000104957bab (in ibtoold)
 13  0x0000000104967b0a (in ibtoold)
 14  0x0000000104966d6f (in ibtoold)
 15  0x00007fff890825c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
Command /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using '~' in your filename. ibtool in Xcode 7 apparently cannot read files with '~' in it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. 
I resolved this by checking my Storyboard for "Circular Segues". 
I do not believe you are supposed to do this on WatchKit, or perhaps it is a bug in the beta. 
I had Segues from view 1,2,3,4, with a final segue back from view 4-1. 
Removing the segue from view 4 to 1 caused this error to go away.